# How to change file path during initializing database in EF 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am starting to develop a project with EF 5, and create a folder beside my web folder and create my database in it.when i try the following code , my database create in **C:\Program File\Microsoft SQl Server\10.0\Data**

```
DBContext.Database.Delete();
DBContext.Database.Create();
```

How i can change the path of my database file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using correct connection string. You are obviously using connection string for SQL server stored database but you want to use connection string with [attached file](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) (that is possible only with SQL Server Express installed).

Comment: I think it will be possible with IDatabaseInitializer.Ook.anyway thanks.Your answer is accepted and upvode for good link.